# Heroku app not recognized as a play application

Tags: maven, heroku, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm using heroku, play framework (v 2.2.1)
and IntelliJ IDEA as IDE.

Everything has already worked but when I added maven as framework support in IntelliJ, when I pushed again, my application wasn't recognized as a play app.

Here is my log when I push:

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.7... done
-----> Installing settings.xml... done
-----> executing /app/tmp/cache/.maven/bin/mvn -B -Duser.home=/tmp/build_78991f
d-32f6-43df-856c-f9059e8fa59d -Dmaven.repo.local=/app/tmp/cache/.m2/repository
s /app/tmp/cache/.m2/settings.xml -DskipTests=true clean install

[....]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
------
   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
   ------
   [INFO] Total time: 2.387s
   [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 07 14:57:19 UTC 2014
   [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/514M
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
   ------
   -----> Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types -> web

   -----> Compressing... done, 74.7MB
   -----> Launching... done, v8
   http://javaepidroid.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

   To git@heroku.com:javaepidroid.git
   f809301..b319499  master -> master
```

My app directory is in the root directory's repository.

Had anyone already has this kind of issue with heroku ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As describe in this [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/blob/master/bin/detect) from github/heroku (for play2 apps) :

You need that your application is :

- a sbt application, ie, one file matching one of these pathes :

  - `root-app/*.sbt`
  - `root-app/project/*.scala`
  - `root-app/.sbt/*.scala`
  - `root-app/project/build.properties`
- a play application, ie. has this file : `root-app/conf/application.conf`

But you may also specify the buildpack of your heroku app :

```
$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git
```

As said in [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack)

Comment: Thank your for your answer.
But the problem really came from maven:

"Heroku recognizes Java apps by the existence of a pom.xml file."
From devcenter heroku.

Comment: Did you test to specify the buildpack ?